# Summary of a data.table using internal order

Tags: r, data.table

I need a way to calculate the third column of this `data.table`.

```
DT=data.table(group=c(1,1,0,0,1,1),x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),ResultNeeded=c(2,2,3,3,4,4))
```

I am guessing the following can be modified to get the result I need.
 `DT[,sum:=sum(x),by=group]`. I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, you just need the correct grouping:

```
DT[, sum := sum(x), by = cumsum(c(F, diff(group) != 0))]
#   group x ResultNeeded sum
#1:     1 1            2   2
#2:     1 1            2   2
#3:     0 1            3   3
#4:     0 2            3   3
#5:     1 2            4   4
#6:     1 2            4   4
```

Answer (score 4):

In the development version of `data.table`, v1.9.5, there's a function `rleid()`, that helps accomplish this in a slightly cleaner way:

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.5+
DT[, ans := sum(x), by=rleid(group)]
#    group x ResultNeeded ans
# 1:     1 1            2   2
# 2:     1 1            2   2
# 3:     0 1            3   3
# 4:     0 2            3   3
# 5:     1 2            4   4
# 6:     1 2            4   4
```

`rleid()` groups consecutive runs of identical values together (named after the base function `rle()`).

You can install the development version by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Comment: This is great, but I need this information for work and they block github.  Therefore the answer below is currently more useful to me.